# Tracking connections and packets of a program

Tags: connection, packet, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, packets

I hope this is quite a simple question.. I've got a compiled .exe program on windows, and I know that it connects to some php resource on some web server and fetch some data. They are just one or two KB, but what I'd like to know is: what's the php resource that it connects to? Is there any program able to trace connections of some other program, on windows?

Thank you very much!
Matteo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is a network protocol analyzer. It lets you capture and interactively browse the traffic running on a computer network.